# Can a VaR equivalent Volatility (VEV) be negative?

Tags: volatility, value-at-risk

As from title, can a VaR equivalent Volatility (VEV) as defined by KID/PRIIPS law be negative?

Answer (score 2):

The formula for VaR equivalent volatility (from [here](https://www.esma.europa.eu/sites/default/files/library/jc_2016_21_final_draft_rts_priips_kid_report.pdf)) is :

$$\frac{\sqrt{3.842 - 2 \ln{\mathrm{VaR}}} - 1.96}{\sqrt{T}}$$

which looks like this (for T=1):

[image: VaR equivalent vol.]

where the x axis is VaR.

Since VaR is bounded between 0 and 1, *no you cannot have a negative VaR equivalent volatility*.

Indeed, from the paper I have stated above, it is written on page 29:

*"The VaR is the percentage of the amount paid that is returned
to the retail investor"*

Therefore, you can say something like this:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{3.842 - 2 \ln{\mathrm{VaR}}} - 1.96}{\sqrt{T}} &\geqslant 0 \\
3.842 - 2 \ln{\mathrm{VaR}} &\geqslant 1.96^2 \\
- 2 \ln{\mathrm{VaR}} &\geqslant 1.96^2 - 3.842\\
- 2 \ln{\mathrm{VaR}} &\geqslant -0.0004\\
\ln{\mathrm{VaR}} &\leqslant 0.0002\\
\mathrm{VaR} &\leqslant e^{0.0002}\\
\mathrm{VaR} &\leqslant 1.00040008001\\
\end{align}$$
Implying that while $\mathrm{VaR} \leqslant 1.00040008001$, the VaR implied vol. is positive.

Comment: Thanks but VaR cannnot be outside the 0-1 interval if it is computed with Cornish Fisher expansion, am I right?

Comment: @Simons123 VaR is the probability of a loss, so if you're computing it to be outside of this integral, then you've made a mistake...

Comment: Ok I got your point but I do not agree. Actually that is because you are giving a theoretical answer. But if you take the VaR as the percentile of an historical distribution over a given horizon you might have (e.g. in a series of all positive returns) a positive VaR.

Comment: So is your question "If i use a flawed method to calculate VaR such that i end up with it outside of the range of actually attainable values of VaR, can this formula result in a negative VEV?" ?

Comment: Actually it is the law that requires that methodology cfr. "as defined by..."
btw I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

VeV under PRIIPS will be negative if the "loss" at the 2.5% cutoff is actually a gain

Imagine a product where you receive a small positive coupon C with probability 0.99, full capital loss with probability 0.01

This product will have a negative VeV and thus score MRM1

Answer (score 1):

VEV can also be negative in the following case (please correct me if I'm wrong):

for a category 3 product characterized by an uconditional protection of capital, you have to calc the pV. With negative risk free rates, dfs are >1 and thus VaR as a percentage of the invested amount is >1. i.e:

Amount=  10,000 ,Residual=   145 , Risk free=   -0.295% , PV=    10,011.75 , VaR [Price Space]= 1.001174886, VEV=   -0.079%

Does it look OK to you?