# Why do regulators assume a risk-neutral world?

Tags: volatility, risk-neutral-measure, value-at-risk, regulatory-formula

It is clear that when pricing derivatives we do this in the risk-neutral measure for known reasons.
In the calculation of the VaR equivalent Volatility (VEV) in the KID-SRRI calculation (see page 9 [here](https://www.esma.europa.eu/sites/default/files/library/2015/11/09_1026_final_kid_srri_methodology_for_publication.pdf)) as well as int the coming regulation of PRIIPs (see [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34149/can-a-var-equivalent-volatility-vev-be-negative) or [this document page 7](http://ec.europa.eu/finance/docs/level-2-measures/priips-delegated-regulation-2017-1473-annex_en.pdf)) the model for the price of the product looks like this
$$
S_t = S_0 \exp \left ( (r-\sigma^2/2)t + \sigma B_t \right),
$$
where r is the risk-free rate.

I am aware that choosing any drift would be difficult but what could be reasons that the regulator chose a risk-neutral setting? Certainly we would need some kind of reward to earn at least the costs of such products.

Comment: Weird, I have been quickly through both of the documents you have quoted but none of them refers to this (Black-Scholes) model.
The only potential reference is on page 21 of the second document you quoted where it is written:
*"historical lognormal returns rt"*. Could you be more explicit please?

Comment: @JejeBelfort in my opinion: if you assume a normal distribution which they do and a drift of a certain form (which they do) then the model is the above - isn't it? They have the term $-\sigma^2/2$ there too. So it should be a geometric Brownian motion.

Comment: @JejeBelfort but you are right, they don't mention the word Brownian motion anywhere.

Comment: Indeed. I will try to formulate an answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, I might have found something related to this in Box 8 of p11 of the first quoted document.

Essentially, you need to compute a Monte Carlo VaR for your structured funds portfolio. Therefore, they advise you to retrieve the drift (ie: risk free rate) *from the interest swap curve*.

The rationale behind the use of this risk-free rate is the essence of risk-neutral pricing: instruments prices should be the same irrespectively from the risk-aversion of each of the market participants. The latter do not need to estimate the expected drift of each asset by imposing their view. The risk-neutral pricing does it for them!

Comment: Yes, if we use the same risk-neutral drift for all products, then we don't have to estimate for each product separately. Neither can different manufacturers choose one. Most probably this is the only solution for a risk-based comparison. I hope to find more arguments in this discussion. Thanks for your input.